# How to show a list of objects with one extra property (which is not part of the class)?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework, listview

I am developing a C# WPF application with Entity Framework 6, database first. Many classes are automatically created based on the structure of the SQL Server database.
I have i.e. a class Artist and a class Title. If I just want to show in WPF a list of Artists or Titles I bind the list to an observable collection of Artists or Titles and all is fine.
But sometime I want to show i.e. a list of Artists plus an extra field/property “Select This”. I.e. the user will see a list of 10 artists with all the properties from the Artist class (generated by EF) and additionally I want to show a checkbox so that the user can select each Artist row.
I guess I can do this by creating a new class based on the Artist class and another new class based on the Title class, etc. But somehow I think there must be an easier way to do this. But how? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classes which EF creates are all PARTIAL classes, which means you can add more attributes to them and use them in your program without affecting the DB.

You can easily extend a class like this:

```
namespace Solution.Project.Model
{
  partial class Title
  {
    public bool IsChecked {get;set;}
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** 
Remember the namespace!

Comment: That sounds like an interesting solution. Do you know if this has any unexpected side effects? I.e. if I save an Artist via EF and I added another partial Artist class does the EF maybe try to save my extra fields to not existing database fields?
I will try this sometime soon and I will find out sooner or later but if you know already any unwanted side effects then I don’t have to discover them by myself.

Comment: Nope, no side effect! the purpose of partial class is so you can extend it, without effecting the main class.

Comment: do you put the extra property to the partial class or the metadatatype class? right now I placed it like you said.

Comment: @CyberNinja what is the metadatatype class? Both classes are the same, one is created by EF and the otherone by the user. In application it will look like one class, but the part which is created by the user doesn't exist on the DB side.

Comment: @NawedNabiZada its basically an attribute class that your user generated partial class uses. [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664465(v=pandp.50).aspx). I end up adding it to the user-generated class.

Comment: @CyberNinja Exactly... You add it to the user created class.

Answer (score 2):

That's what we have MVVM for..

You should have a view model in between your EF Generated models and view, wherein you can do all such manipulations, it might sound lengthy right now but I can assure you its the finest way going fwd.

And just to answer your query here you can have an additional checkbox column. for that

- you need to use a DataGrid on UI,
- have a checkbox column in grid,
- bind each checkbox checked to a command/eventhandler..
- get the item there and play with it.

Comment: In principle I understand that MVVM makes sense – for “big” projects. I develop this application by myself and it is my first WPF C# project. In the moment I don’t want to make it too complicated. My priority is to get things done and learn how to use the basics of C#, WPF, EF, etc.
About your answer: “bind each checkbox checked to a command/eventhandler” I thought I have to bind one DataGrid with all its columns to one List (ObservableCollection< Artist>). Is it possible to bind different columns to different objects? Or is your idea to have a checkbox and work with the Click event?

Comment: myIdea would be to bind the desired column with your collection, and have an Unbound check box column and to handle its clicks/checks/unchecks/whatevers

Answer (score 1):

You may be asking for how to populate a dataGrid using an anonymous type that is generated from a linq query, like the result of a join query and so on, here a basic example how that works :

**first** lets define a dataGrid and bind its column to the properties
   you are expecting in your anonymous type object

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="Dg" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
       <DataGrid.Columns>
           <DataGridTextColumn Header="Clm1" Binding="{Binding Clm1}"/>
           <DataGridTextColumn Header="Clm2" Binding="{Binding Clm2}"/>
           <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Clm3" Binding="{Binding Clm3,Mode=OneWay}"/>
       </DataGrid.Columns>
   </DataGrid>
```

**then** here how to populate that grid using an anonymous type

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> DataGridItems { get; set; }   
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataGridItems=new ObservableCollection<Item>()
        {
            new Item()
            {
                Clm1 = "Item1"
            }, new Item()
            {
                Clm1 = "Item2"
            }, new Item()
            {
                Clm1 = "Item3"
            }
        };
        Dg.ItemsSource = DataGridItems.Select((item) =>

            new
            {
                Clm1 = item.Clm1,
                Clm2= "Item2",
                Clm3=true
            }
        );
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public String Clm1 { get; set; }      
}
```

make sure to use the same Binding property name used in the dataGrid.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and all that code. I understand your idea. As far as I see this will be more work if I have i.e. 10 columns. And if I want to do one list for Artists and another list for Titles it is double the work. This is what I wanted to avoid – if possible. Maybe I have to do this work but I thought I better ask the question to be sure there is no easier solution which I don’t know (yet).

Comment: what you mean double the work !, if you are referring to defining the columns, you don't need to, just set the AutoGenerateColumns TO true!